# Python & Pandas: Comparing instances over two different csvs

Tags: python, pandas, csv

New to Python and Pandas, any assistance appreciated.

I have two csv's, `control.csv` and `replies.csv`, both of which contain columns `user_id` and `text` (see below).

`control.csv`

```
user_id,    text
4102,   text0
5109,   text1
5349,   text2
```

`replies.csv`

```
user_id,    text
4102,   texta
4102,   textb
5109,   textc
```

I'd like to count the number of times the values in `user_id` in `control.csv` appears in `replies.csv`. I'd then like to write that count in a new column in `control.csv` called `replies`. The desired output would like:

```
user_id,    text,   replies
4102,   text0,  2
5109,   text1,  1
5349,   text2,  0
```

I can generate the number of occurrences of `user_id` from `replies.csv` via the code below. However, I'm uncertain what to do next to match `user_id` from `control.csv` with the value count in `replies.csv`.

```
import pandas as pd 

df_replies = pd.read_csv('replies.csv')
df_control = pd.read_csv('control.csv')

reply_count = df_replies['user_id'].value_counts()
```

All suggestions on how to proceed? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try via `groupby()`+`count()` to get the count of replies then map values by using `map()` and fill NaN values to 0 with `fillna()`:

```
control['replies']=(control['user_id'].map(replies.groupby('user_id')['text'].count())
                                      .fillna(0,downcast='infer'))
```

OR

Same approach like above but with `merge()`:

```
count=replies.groupby('user_id')['text'].count().reset_index(name='replies')
control=control.merge(count,on='user_id',how='left').fillna(0,downcast='infer')
```

output of `control`:

```
  user_id   text    replies
0   4102    text0   2
1   5109    text1   1
2   5349    text2   0
```

Comment: Many thanks! I tried the `merge()` method you described, and it worked perfectly! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @DanielHutchinson glad it helped....happy coding **:)**

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# create data
df_control  = pd.DataFrame([[4102,'text0'],[5109,'text1',[5349,'text2']],columns=['user_id','text'])
df_replies = pd.DataFrame([[4102,'texta'],[4102,'textb'], [5109,'textc']],columns=['user_id','text'])

 # count value:isin the key process
df_replies_in_control = df_replies[df_replies['user_id'].isin(set(df_control['user_id']))]
df_replies_in_control_counts = df_replies_in_control['user_id'].value_counts()


# import num into control data df:give zero where not show in control
df_control_add_num = df_control.copy()
df_control_add_num['replies'] = [df_replies_in_control_counts[num]  if num in 
df_replies_in_control_counts.index else 0 for num in df_control['user_id']]
```

**df_control_add_num** is the result.I hope this will slove your issue.

Comment: Many thanks! I get an syntax error in the line `df_replies_in_control = `, is something missing?

Answer (score 1):

Using chaining

```py
…
(control
    .merge(replies, how="left", on="user_id")
    .groupby(by="user_id")
    .agg(replies_=("text_y", "count"))
)
```

We left join control data with replies. This will result in NaN where data exists in control but not in replies. That is why count data from replies.